# Can you have match and nomatch rules in same group in Keyman source file?

Tags: unicode, keyboard

Is it possible to have both a match and nomatch rule within the same group  in a Keyman source file (.kmn)? Ie:

```
match > use(deadkeys)
nomatch > use(touch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and makes sense. However, somewhat less obviously, the pair of [`match`](http://help.keyman.com/developer/language/reference/match) and [`nomatch`](http://help.keyman.com/developer/language/reference/nomatch) rules will not match all possible events into the group, because the [`nomatch` rule does not necessarily fire when a rule is not matched](http://help.keyman.com/developer/language/reference/nomatch):

> `nomatch` will not be fired in a `using keys` group if the current keystroke does not produce a character in normal use (for example, modified keys, function keys).

Comment: If the key [T_CIRCUMFLEX] is pressed but no rules within current group address this key, what would the expected behaviour be, considering a match and nomatch rules, as stated in question?

Comment: Given `[T_CIRCUMFLEX]`  is a custom key on a touch layout, it has no default output, so would not fire either `match` or `nomatch`.